# Customize Visual Studio Solution Platform Name Using CMAKE

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to customize the Solution Platform Name when creating Visual Studio solutions using CMake?

(Note: All of the below was tested with CMake 3.12.0 and CMake 3.15.0-rc1)

Based on tests with some open source projects (CEF etc.) and also a simplified demo project (https://github.com/cognitivewaves/CMake-VisualStudio-Example) it seems like CMake creates solution files using the following pattern (for 32-bit):

```
...
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
        ...
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        ...
    EngGlobalSection
    ...
EndGlobal
...
```

Generated using:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14" -Tv140
```

---

However, I would like to create the solutions using 'x86' instead of 'Win32' for the Solution Platform name to match the default formats created by VS 2015 (Update 3) and VS 2019 for example.

Like so:

```
...
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
        ...
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF0}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        ...
    EngGlobalSection
    ...
EndGlobal
...
```

---

Specifying 'x86' at the command line

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 x86" -Tv140
```

seems to be unsupported (Error: Could not create name generator ...).

Likewise for using the `host` variable

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14" -Tv140,host=x86
```

(error with CMake 3.12.0: contains invalid field 'host=x86'; no error with CMake 3.15.0-RC1 but doesn't seem to have an effect either)

or via

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14" -Tv140 -DCMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_HOST_ARCHITECTURE=x86
```

(no error but doesn't seem to have any effect either)

Is there another argument I am missing / overlooked in the documentation?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and with best regards,

-T